# NodeJS Amazon AWS Submit Feed Generic Error

Tags: node.js, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am trying to submit a product feed to AWS and I keep getting a generic error related to the XML I am sending

I have gone through all the .xsd files and come up what I believe to be correct xml but apparently not :(

#### The Error

```
{
  "MessageID": "1",
  "ResultCode": "Error",
  "ResultMessageCode": "25",
  "ResultDescription": "We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed."
}
```

#### How I am creating the content

```
const getContent = (upc) => `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>${process.env.MERCHANT_ID}</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
          <Product>
              <SKU>${upc}</SKU>
          </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this just means a value in the xml is malformed. It helped a lot to search the xsd files for the specific variable I was trying to tie a value to and then it provides the restrictions on that value (i.e. AmazonOrderId has a regex validation associated with it that restricts the value to be in the structure of 123-1234567-1234567). After I manually ran through this process for each variable I was able to submit a feed finally but now I have to have an associated OrderAcknowledgement which I am working through.